# jaxb: Prevent creation of redundant collections?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using JAXB for generating Java code for parsing an XML file, and whenever an element may occur repeatedly in the XML, the generated classes contain an extra level of indirection via a collection in a separate class that seems redundant to me and makes the code using these classes somewhat inelegant. To illustrate what I mean, assume my XML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <columns>
        <column id="c1">
            <order>1</order>
            <name>first</name>
            <type>text</type>
        </column>

        <column id="c2">
            <order>2</order>
            <name>second</name>
            <type>text</type>
        </column>

        <column id="c3">
            <order>3</order>
            <name>third</name>
            <type>text</type>
        </column>
    </column>
</columns>
```

And the schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="configuration" type="Configuration"/>

    <xs:complexType name="ColumnList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="Column" name="column" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Column">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="order"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            <xs:element name="type">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="text"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="number"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="date"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="format" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="optional" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, if I let JAXB generate my classes I get a class that looks like

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Configuration", propOrder = {
    "columns",
    "providers"
})
public class Configuration {
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ColumnList columns;
    // ...
}
```

With ColumnList being just

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ColumnList", propOrder = {
    "column"
})
public class ColumnList {
    protected List<Column> column;
    // ...
}
```

Which makes accessing the Columns a bit clunky because I always have to do something like `config.getColumns().getColumn()`.

So my question would be: is there any way I can tell JAXB to omit this extra level of indirection? Instead of Creating the `ColumnList` type which just contains a `List<Column>`, could it not just use a `List<Column>` in the `Configuration` class, so I can just write `List<Column> = config.getColumns();`?

The schema definition is under my control, so changing it is no problem, but I suspect that alone won't be sufficient. I suspect specifying an explicit JAXB binding might do the trick but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the `ColumnList` type and specify `Configuration` to have a collection of `Column` elements named *columns*.
The generated code should no longer have the ColumnList class nor the extra level of indirection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="configuration" type="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="Column" name="columns" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="Column">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:integer" name="order"/>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            <xs:element name="type">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="text"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="number"/>
                        <xs:enumeration value="date"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="format" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="optional" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: But if I am not mistaken that would mean changing the structure of the XML so the `column` elements are no longer contained in a `columns` parent element - they'd just be lumped together on the same level as the other elements in the `configuration` element (there are more types in my case, I just omitted them for brevity). That is a change I'd prefer to avoid, because I think keeping elements of the same type together in a subelement makes the XML easier to read for a human.

Comment: Yes, that would mean changing the structure of the XML. Sadly I have no experience keeping the parent (wrapper) element but _not_ including it in the generated code.